# Calcular el peso de un directorio (carpeta) en php

Tags: php

Estoy queriendo calular el peso de un directorio en php para luego mostrar los datos según el ejemplo.

```
Ejemplo:

Almecenamiendo
50 GB (14.12%) de 353 GB utilizados
```

Tengo la siguiente función, dónde me muestra una lista con los subdirectorios.

```
<?php

    $dir = ('D:\archivos');
    echo "Total : " .Fsize($dir);
    function Fsize($dir)
        {
            if (is_dir($dir))
                {
                    if ($gd = opendir($dir))
                        {
                            $cont = 0;
                            while (($archivo = readdir($gd)) !== false)
                                {
                                    if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != ".." )
                                        {
                                            if (is_dir($archivo))
                                                {
                                                    $cont += Fsize($dir."/".$archivo);
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                    $cont += sprintf("%u",filesize($dir."/".$archivo));
                                                    echo  "archivo : " . $dir."/".$archivo . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . filesize($dir."/".$archivo)."<br />";
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                            closedir($gd);
                        }
                }
            return $cont;
        }
        
?>
```

me muestra un total `3891923`, pero no es el peso real, al validar el directorio su peso es de `191791104 bytes`

me podrían ayudar, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

he probado tu código... 
Funciona correctamente, quizás te falte algo que sumar y ya 
Las condiciones de prueba fueron las siguientes:

- Probado en la carpeta de Descargas
- Quitados todos los directorios (solo archivos dentro)
- Peso obtenido de las Propiedades ([link](https://i.gyazo.com/18897dbb0a2edef17379c93445ffd4a3.png))

Resultado:

```
PESO DE DESCARGAS: 2,68 GB (2.881.723.298 bytes)
Total : PESO OBTENIDO: 2881723298
```

Y las modificaciones hechas, las puedes ver en el código acá abajo.
Moví el `$cont` e imprimir por texto el resultado esperado antes del `return`.
Además añadí un `cleartstatcache();` al inicio de la función.

```
<?php
$dir = ('C:/Users/Usuario/Downloads');
echo "Total : " . Fsize($dir);
function Fsize($dir)
{
    clearstatcache();
    $cont = 0;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($gd = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($archivo = readdir($gd)) !== false) {
                if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                    if (is_dir($archivo)) {
                        $cont += Fsize($dir . "/" . $archivo);
                    } else {
                        $cont += sprintf("%u", filesize($dir . "/" . $archivo));
                        //echo  "archivo : " . $dir . "/" . $archivo . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . filesize($dir . "/" . $archivo) . "<br />";
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($gd);
        }
    }
    echo "PESO DE DESCARGAS: 2,68 GB (2.881.723.298 bytes)</br>";
    return "PESO OBTENIDO: ".$cont;
}
?>
```